# Turnover Calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 SQL tables. 1) Headcount 2)Leavers 3) Year-Month

I need to find out attrition. Attrition formula = (Total Leavers/ Avg. headcount ) * 12 / (No.of Months)
**
Total Leavers** = Running total ( Example : Jul =10 , Aug = 20, Sep=5) then output should be Jul =10, Aug=30, Sep=35.(Basically Running Total)

**Avg. Headcount** = Sum of Headcount number/Total no.of months ( Example : Jul = 100 , Aug=250, Sep=280) then output should be Jul=100 . Aug=175 , Sep=210 -(Jul = 100 , Aug =  (100 + 250)/2, Sep = (100+250+280)/3 and so on ..... Basically Moving Average)

No.of Months = Our fiscal year starts from Jul-jun. So, Jul=1, Aug=2 ... etc . Pulling it from 'Year-Month' table which I created. It has 3 columns- Year | Month | Number

This is how the data is:

[image]

I need to calculate Turnover by Business Head, Group Manager and Location.

Output should be like

CreatedDate  |  Location |  Business Head | Reporting Manager | Leavers Count | Avg. Headcount | Attrition

I want all of them in single query not a separate one for each column.

Can someone please help with the query? I t would be a great help to me.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Which dbms are you actually using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great startt when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: If JOIN, a few questions on tables: YearMonth(y int,m int,n int) where n - month in calendar year? or fiscal year? or identity?
Headcount(y int,m int,headcount int) where m is month in calendar year or fiscal year?
Leavers - no assumption?

Comment: Provide data as formatted text table not image.